# Understanding the proof of the Crofton formula

Tags: geometry, proof-explanation

I am trying to understand the proof of the Crofton formula. Unfortunately, I'm already struggling at the beginning of the proof. Can someone explain me why we get the equations in (17)?

[image: Crofton formula proof]

$$(17)\quad\quad\quad\begin{cases}
\frac{de_1}{ds}\,=\,a_2e_2\,+a_3e_3 \\ 
\frac{de_2}{ds}\,=\,-a_2e_1\,+a_1e_3   \\ 
\frac{de_3}{ds}\,=\,-a_3e_1-a_1e_2 
\end{cases}
$$

Comment: Please format any mathematics using LaTeX; just pasting images of mathematics is frowned upon.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The decomposition of vectors $\frac{de_k}{ds}, \ k=1,2,3$ onto the basis $(e_1,e_2,e_3)$ gives rise "a priori" to 9 distinct functions $b_{ij}(s)$ :

$$\begin{cases}\frac{de_1}{ds}&=&b_{11}e_1+b_{12}e_2+b_{13}e_3\\
\frac{de_2}{ds}&=&b_{21}e_1+b_{22}e_2+b_{23}e_3\\
\frac{de_3}{ds}&=&b_{31}e_1+b_{32}e_2+b_{33}e_3\end{cases}\tag{1}$$

The unexpected result is that instead of having 9 independent entries, the matrix of this differential system has only 3 of them, being antisymmetrical:

$$\begin{cases}\frac{de_1}{ds}&=& \ \ \ 0e_1+a_{2}e_2+a_{3}e_3\\
\frac{de_2}{ds}&=&-a_{2}e_1+0e_2+a_{1}e_3\\
\frac{de_3}{ds}&=& -a_{3}e_1-a_{1}e_2+0e_3\end{cases}\tag{2}$$

Formulas (2), discovered by [Frenet-Serret](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frenet%E2%80%93Serret_formulas),use in an essential way the fact that the parameter is curvilinear abscissa.

Let us establish (2) from (1).

Let us define the matrix

$$E(s):=(e_1(s)|e_2(s)|e_3(s))^T\tag{3}$$
(where the $e_k(s)$ are considered as column vectors).

Let us start by expressing in the following matricial way the fact that basis $(e_1,e_2,e_3)$ is orthogonal with unit vectors (the $e_i \cdot e_j=\delta_{i,j}$ of your text):

$$E(s)E(s)^T=I\tag{4}$$

(otherwise said, $E(s)^T=E(s)^{-1}$: $E(s)$ is an orthogonal matrix).

With these notations, differential system (1) can be written under the form

$$\frac{dE(s)}{ds}=B(s) E(s)\tag{5}$$

or the equivalent form

$$\frac{dE(s)}{ds}E(s)^{-1}=B(s)\tag{6}$$

Now, differentiation of relationship (4) with respect to $s$ gives:

$$E(s)'E(s)^T+E(s)^TE'(s)^T=0 \ \iff  \tag{7}$$

$$\underbrace{E(s)' E(s)^T}_{= \ B(s) \ \text{using (6)}}=-\underbrace{E(s)^TE'(s)^T}_{B(s)^T}$$

establishing the antisymmetry of matrix $B(s).$

Comment: First, i want to thank you that you took your time to answer me. So, i read the wikipedia article about the Frenet formulas and i really thought hours about it but i just don‘t see the connection between the $a_i$ in (17) and the curvature/torsion in the wikipedia article.

Comment: What are these $a_i‘s$ in the first place? For me they come like out of nothing.

Comment: This adding has been done. I have also modified the text in other parts in order for it to be understandable. One thing is sure : the interpretation of the $a_i$ in terms of curvature, torsion etc. is probably unimportant for what you want to do with the $a_k$s.

Comment: Can I ask you the references of the book/article you use ?

Comment: This adding has been done. I have also modified the text in other parts in order for it to be understandable. One thing is sure : the interpretation of the $a_k$s in terms of curvature, torsion etc. is probably unimportant for what you want to do with them.

Comment: Wow. Hopefully one day I‘ll become as smart as you are. The book is called „Studies in global geometry and analysis“ by S.S. Chern. You can borrow it from the Internet Archive.

Comment: It's not a question of being "smart", only long practise... Besides, dealing with Crofton, I have always been fascinated by these astonishing results of Stochastic Geometry connecting length, areas, etc... Thanks for the reference. (Chern is a great mathematician). I have been studying these topics at first with a book of Santalo "Integral Geometry and Geometric Probability"